# An Intelligent Property builded in Execution Time by Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have done a quite few interesting things with reflection. Now I'm wondering, is it possible to add a code to an auto property (`propName { get; set; }`) with reflection?

I mean can I get a `PropertyInfo` and change the code of the getter or the setter?

Is it possible? How can I do it? Or what the key words to I google this (I'm asking because everything that I found is about how get or set a property with reflection not alter the getter and the setter).

Comment: the keyword is: reflection emit

Answer (score 0):

At runtime yo can do it for virtual properties by creating proxy types inherited from your classes and using interception. One of the best and fastest ways to do it is Castle.DynamicProxy ([Good tutorial](http://kozmic.net/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/)) or using Reflection Emit IL Manipulating ([example](https://grahammurray.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/dynamically-generating-types-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged/) + [FluentIL](https://github.com/ElemarJR/FluentIL/blob/master/demos/DynamicProxy/src/DynamicProxy.Tests/ProxyBuilderTests.cs) is quite interesting).

At compile time you can do it with static IL weaving with the help of PostSharp (commercial, uses Profiler API) or [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) (free, uses awesome [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) behind the scenes, like [LinFU](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23333/Introducing-LinFu-Part-VI-LinFu-AOP-Pervasive-Meth)). I think Telerik ORM Tools use Profiler API to create dynamic proxy objects with useful/support functionality, for example.